# Non-static method next() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, static, scope, non-static

I am trying to parse out a `mm/dd/yyyy` formatted date into separate fields, but I get the following error when I try to compile:

> non-static method next() cannot be referenced from a static context

What could be causing the error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem39
{

    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {

    boolean isLeapYear =false;
    int maxDay=0;
    String stringDate;

    System.out.println("Enter the date in mm/dd/yyyy format. ");  //user input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);                    //read input
    String date=Scanner.next();                                //store input
    String temp=date.split("/");  //parse date
    int month=IntegerParseInt(temp[1]);
    int day=IntegerParseInt(temp[0]);
    int year=IntegerParseInt(temp[2]);
```

Comment: It could be because `next()` is a `Scanner` *instance* method, and you're not calling it on a scanner instance. The parsing is also incorrect.

Comment: @Petro, why would the OP's confusion merit a downvote? Isn't that why SO exists, to clear up such common confusions?

Comment: also change `IntegerParseInt` to `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: @kaveman, it's just that difference between static/instance method is very basic java knowledge. Also there are three questions on stackoverflow "why non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" answered already.

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
String date = Scanner.next();
```

to:

```
String date = keyboard.next();
```

[`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) is an instance method, so you must call it on an instance of the class Scanner.

Also, change:

```
String temp = date.split("/");
```

to:

```
String[] temp = date.split("/");
```

the [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method returns a string array.

Comment: the only answer to actually explain the answer!

Comment: Now it is complaining about incompatible types on the next line  String temp=date.split("/");  //parse date

Answer (score 1):

It should be `keyboard.next()` not `Scanner.next()`.

Comment: Hi Ian and welcome. You shouldn't say (write) thanks literally, but upvote the answer (the Δ beneath the anwer) and accept the best one (with the √). This gives the answerer reputation and avoids lengthy dialogs ("Thanks"/"You're welcome"/...).

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
String date = keyboard.next();
```

instead of

```
String date = Scanner.next();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code:

```
String date=Scanner.next();
```

to:

```
String date = keyboard.next();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) not `IntegerParseInt`.

Also change to this

```
String date = keyboard.next();
```